# what's the difference between using 1/2n and 1/n in cost function in Linear Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, linear-regression, mse

Sometimes people use 1/2n in cost function, but we know that another name for cost function is Mean Squared Error. But for MSE, 1/n is justifiable than 1/2n, so is there any term that we call when we use 1/2n ? Also what's the difference between using 1/n and 1/2n ?

Comment: See also: [Why is there a 2
 at the denominator of the mean squared error function](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/29526), [Why do we have to divide by 2 in the ML squared error cost function?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/52157)